# Discord.js: check if part of array is undefined

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am making a discord bot for my server, and I want to include a `%react` command. The way it works, you do `react #channel messageid emote` and it makes the bot react to a message. Currently the code I have works great, except I want to eliminate all errors and warnings because I really hate opening command prompt or terminal and seeing pages upon pages of text. The `try{}` statement picks up on everything except the last part (the emote) for some reason, so I tried to implement an `if()` statement to detect if the 4th part of the message is undefined. However this isn't working, and I can't figure out why. 
My code is this:

```js
var splitMessage = message.content.split(' ')
if (splitMessage[0] === "%react") {
            if (message.member.roles.cache.has("staff-role-id") || message.author.id === "random-user-who-wanted-perms") {
                var channel = splitMessage[1].replace(/[<>:#]/gi, "");
                channel = client.channels.cache.get(channel);
                var messageid = splitMessage[2]
                var emote = splitMessage[3];
                emote = emote.replace(/[<>:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]/gi, "")
                 if (typeof splitMessage[2] !== "undefined" && splitMessage[2] && splitMessage[2] !== null) { 
                 
                  //executes no matter what

                    var emotetest = client.emojis.get(splitMessage[2])
                    try {
                        //console.log(channel)
                        const m = await channel.messages.fetch(messageid)
                        m.react(emote);
                        message.channel.send("Reaction added!")
                    } catch (e) { message.channel.send("Invalid Syntax, please check you have the right channel and ID"); }
                }
                else {
                    message.channel.send("Please provide an emote")
                }
            }
            else {
                message.channel.send("Insufficient Permissions")
            }
        }
```

I have no idea why it isn't working (I feel like I have tried everything). Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

When using asynchronous code in a `try` block, you need to `await` the promise for it to be caught.

```js
const rejectingFn = msg => new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(msg), 500))
window.addEventListener('unhandledrejection', ({reason}) => console.log('unhandled promise rejection:', reason))

// Doesn't work
try {
  rejectingFn('uncaught')
} catch (error) {
  console.log('caught error:', error)
}

(async () => {
  // Works
  try {
    await rejectingFn('caught')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('caught error:', error)
  }
})()
```

You have 2 unhandled promises in your `try` block: `m.react(emote)` and `message.channel.send("Reaction added!")`. To ensure that all errors are caught, use `await`.

Additionally, the other calls to `message.channel.send` are also unhandled, so you could use `await` with those, wrap everything in `try` and do something like log the errors to avoid unhandled promise rejections (which will make Node.js terminate the process with a non-zero exit code in the future).

Comment: Great (I already am using an async function)! Which parts should I add await to? I don't understand that part...

Comment: @Komali `await m.resct(emote); await message.channel.send("Reaction added!")`

Comment: hmm that doesn't seem to do anything. Any other ideas?